# How to pass parameter in javascript's url?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function to open the new window when we click the link but i want to pass the value "id" to another page. How can I add the value to url> 
Following is the code...

```
 <SCRIPT language="JavaScript1.2">
    function openoldgurantorwindow()
      {
     window.open("enter code heregurrantor/old",
    "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=700,height=700");
    }
    </SCRIPT>
    <a href="javascript: openoldgurantorwindow()">Click to view old Guarantors</a>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So where is the value `id`. Where will you get it from? PHP or javascript??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `id`  or any other parameter as query params like shown below:

```
function openoldgurantorwindow(id) {
    window.open("http://example.com?id=" + id,
            "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=700,height=700");
}
```

And can be retrieved at next page in `PHP` code in `$_GET` variable.